# React Quill js. How to console log on change handler?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-quill

I'm currently creating a blog dashboard, I'm beginner on web dev. and for the editor I'm using the React quill..
in the documentation there is a tutorial with on change handler. but it just console log "text change", and I'm trying to change the console log "text-change" with anything that I type on the quill editor.

My question is. How to do it?
here my code for the `useEffect`:

```
   const { quill, quillRef } = useQuill();
    const [isi, setisi] = useState('')
    
   useEffect(() => {
      if (quill) {
        quill.on('text-change', () => { 
            console.log('teks-changed! ')
        })
        
        
        
      }
    }, [quill]);
```

Comment: quill.getContents(); returns the current content on quill editor

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use quill.getText() to get the text. here is the full working code below.

```
const { quill, quillRef } = useQuill();
  React.useEffect(() => {
    if (quill) {
      quill.on('text-change', (e) => {
        const text = quill.getText();
        console.log(text);
      });
    }
  }, [quill]);
```

Comment: lemme try first sam

Comment: it works bro.. btw i just wondering that, can i pass the text into state? and post it into DB with axios?

Comment: you can simply call your function before console.log. basically,  you need to declare params using use state and then call setstate function before console.log

Comment: im sorry i dont know i clicked it

Answer (score 3):

You've two options for getting quill data:

1. [Delta](https://quilljs.com/docs/delta/)
2. [innerHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML)

in the next example I've logged both:

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import { useQuill } from "react-quilljs";
import "quill/dist/quill.snow.css"; // Add css for snow theme

export default () => {
  const { quill, quillRef } = useQuill();

  useEffect(() => {
    if (quill) {
      quill.on("text-change", (delta) => {
        console.log("delta", delta);
        console.log("innerHTML", quill.root.innerHTML);
      });
    }
  }, [quill]);

  return (
    <div style={{ width: 500, height: 300 }}>
      <div ref={quillRef} />
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: lemme try first bruh

Comment: hi! thats works.. but what is the difference ? im just beginner and just knewin that

Answer (score 0):

inside `useEffect` you'd have to `quill.on()` and inside that use `quill.getText()` to get the data.

like this >>

```
useEffect(() => {
    if (quill) {
      quill.on('text-change', (e) => {
        const data = quill.getText();
        console.log(data);
      });
    }
  }, [quill])
```